# How to set a fixed background in ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, background, android-viewpager

I have a Fragment that contains a ViewPager which allows the user to swipe through three fragments.

Here's the problem: I want the ViewPager to have a background that remains fixed when the user swipes through the fragments. I tried setting an image in my drawable as the background of the ViewPager but that didn't work.. Here's my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    tools:context=".fragments.cash.WalletFragment">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:background="@drawable/revenue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are many ways to achieve this feat, this approach works for me:

Simply create a FrameLayout with two children: Your ViewPager and the view(s) you want to use as the background of your viewpager. Here's an example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    tools:context=".fragments.cash.WalletFragment">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/my_smiling_face"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that you can replace the Imageview with a layout (e.g RelativeLayout) containing all the composite views you want your background to contain.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!